# Blockchain dApp: How end user use dApp without care of Ethereum Account

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, decentralized-applications

I want to develop a dApp (Smart Contract) on Ethereum and have a mobile application on top of it.
My concern is: every time we interact with Smart Contract to inquiry or change data, we need a account as well as a certain number of ETH used as Gas. It looks no problem on the development environment, but getting into trouble in real life, I mean about user experience (UX).

- Whenever a user download and install the app, we will create for them an Ethereum account. BUT where they can get ETH to interact with Smart Contract? And absolutely, they don't care and don't want to be bothered with exchange ETH.

I have an alternative solution: we have only 1 Ethereum account with some ETH in their and act as the Proxy to the Smart Contract. Whenever user's request come, we delegate the request to Smart Contract and return to user. BUT it seems we will lost the main characteristic of Blockhain: Decentralized :) Who know we might arbitrarily change the Smart Contract without user attention.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can send some ether to each new user that is just enough to call your contract.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think the problem is a new user doesn't have ETH to execute the contract so why don't we send them some ETH to do it? It's a straight answer. User will not have to care about Ethereum at all.